# SSRS SQL report builder deleting column

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a problem with SSRS report builder. Basically what I want to do is to delete a column. I have a report that someone else made and there is 1 column (xxx) that no longer exists in data source tables so I need to delete it.

When I go to query designer and delete this column from the code and run it there, it works. I close query designer window and see that list of columns (fields) is updated now and xxx column is not there. Then, I delete this column manually in designer (default screen) and when I try to run the report, It doesn't work:

"The Value expression for the text box ‘XXXDataField’ refers to the field ‘xxx’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case."

But that field should be already deleted. So I don't know what else I can do, or what it can be linked to. I just want to delete it. Any Idea?

Thank you

Comment: If your dataset does not contain `xxx` but your DataTable has this error is normal

Comment: well I deleted it from the table as I wrote

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset does not contain xxx but your DataTable has this error is normal

You either delete that column from your table or at lease delete DataSet Binding from table so that SSRS does not try to retrieve that column from DataSet

Comment: ok so How do I delete dataset binding? As I wrote, I already deleted that column from table and also it is not in the list of fields

Answer (score 0):

It will be a reference to the field in another field. For example, if you deleted a column that showed an OrderShipped status, then you might have another text box highlighted based on this.

The error is telling you which textbox is in error. So, click somewhere on the designer, then in the properties window, right at the top, click the dropdown which allows you to choose specific report items, choose `XXXDataField` (the one named in the error message) and then check the value expression. In there you will find the reference to the column you deleted.

Comment: sorry, which properties do you mean?

Comment: Ah, if you are using report builder then you cannot choose the selected object from a list (I use Visual Studio). In which case you will have to click on each textbox until you find the one called "XXXDataField". When you have the properties panel open (hit F4 if you can't see it). The object/item name is shown at the top of the properties panel,